# how to design android project using custom view?

Tags: android, custom-view, android-custom-view

this is not a question that has an exact answer but I need some advice how to develop my application.

I have a web service that sends me all the application information (fonts, styles etc). the purpose is to use the service in multiple devices. I created the data model for my application. Thus I have everything I needed. Now I need to visualise my app upon data coming from server. I thought about custom view, or perhaps multiple custom views to visualise the data upon what kind of view it needs. is that a right choice? or can you give me better advices? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that's a good way to do it.  You can create a Library project where you implement those views so you can use them in multiple apps.  Just remember you need to specify the full package name in the layout xml.

Comment: Actually I've designed a package that includes my page objects already. I have no problem with using my objects there. What I need to is to find the best way to visualize my data. Thus I need more android than java

Answer (score 1):

The [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) is maybe what you're looking for. It is possible to build complete apps using the WebView, without the user ever noticing that all he sees is made up of HTML and CSS. It can feel pretty native.

If your server not only provides data but also appearance details such as styles, etc.. Then really, the most natural solution seems to be the WebView. You can actually build HTML pages (or fragments) server side, and deliver them to the devices.

The WebView is very customizable. You can deactivate zooming, etc... and with the right CSS rules, your UI will render consistently across devices.

And with [WebView.addJavascriptInterface()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29), you can easily interact with your Java classes and thus the data model.

Comment: Thanks but WebView is not something I'm looking for. I need to use all android components but not only webview, webview is mostly about web programming but I need to do more than web, like I need to use camera, sensors, etc. I think webview would not be a right choice, thanks anyway

Comment: You're welcome. WebView on Android isn't restricted to web programming. You can access sensors by exposing some Java objects in JavaScript as I mentioned. That said, your question isn't detailed enough, in my opinion.

Comment: I was reviewing my questions and bro you are quite right, I was an absoulute beginner, only one month android guy :)